# Deployment of a model containing The Universal Sentence Encoder Multilingual on google ai-platform

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I have been trying to use `The Universal Sentence Encoder Multilingual` for transfer learning with tensorflow(1.15) keras. I used sentence encoder as KerasLayer in the Sequential model. After the training, I save my model as `saved_model.pb` using `tf.saved_model.save`. Here is my model:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow_text

USE_V3 = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual-large/3"
my_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(), dtype=tf.string),
        hub.KerasLayer(USE_V3, trainable=False),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax"),
    ]
)
my_model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

I use google ai-platform for my training and prediction. There is no problem with the training, it trains and saves the model on google cloud storage. When I deploy my saved model for prediction, a release version is created in models section of the ai-platform. I used TensorFlow as Framework, python 3.7, runtime version 1.15. When I use `TEST & USE` section to get a sample prediction, it gives this error: (I also tried the api, same error is returned)

```
{
  "error": "Prediction failed: Error during model execution: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.NOT_FOUND, details=\"{{function_node __inference_signature_wrapper_139623}} {{function_node __inference_signature_wrapper_139623}} {{function_node __inference___call___137889}} {{function_node __inference___call___137889}} {{function_node __inference_restored_function_body_100331}} {{function_node __inference_restored_function_body_100331}} [_Derived_]{{function_node __inference___call___55591}} {{function_node __inference___call___55591}} Op type not registered 'SentencepieceOp' in binary running on localhost. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.\n\t [[{{node StatefulPartitionedCall}}]]\n\t [[StatefulPartitionedCall]]\n\t [[muse_sentiment_classification/embedding/StatefulPartitionedCall]]\n\t [[StatefulPartitionedCall]]\n\t [[StatefulPartitionedCall]]\")"
}
```

In short, `SentencepieceOp` (from tensorflow_text) cannot be found in the prediction machine. Then, I tried to use this workaround I found [here](https://medium.com/@jeffrey.jedele/deploying-tensorflow-models-with-custom-operators-on-google-ai-platform-1c6af7f583bb). This post used the workaround for lacking `SentencepieceEncodeSparse`, but I think the reason is similar. I created my own `Custom Prediction Routine` as suggested and put the dependency for `tensorflow_text` in it. Model size limit is 500MB for the Custom Prediction Routine and my model is ~350MB. When I try to create new version for my model, this time it does not create the release version and gives this memory error:

```
Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error: Model requires more memory than allowed. Please try to decrease the model size and re-deploy. If you continue to experience errors, please contact support.
```

1st question: Is there a proper way to deploy a model that uses `Universal Sentence Encoder Multilingual` in ai-platform without Custom Prediction Routine workaround?

2nd question: If I have to use Custom Prediction Routine, how can I solve this memory problem? I mean I only have 1 extra Dense Layer. How can I decrease the memory usage?

EDIT: I used both gcloud (v296.0.1) and cloud console for the deployment with the same configurations. These are the deployment scripts for both framework `TensorFlow` and `Custom Prediction Routine`:

TensorFlow deployment:

```sh
MODEL_DIR="gs://my-bucket--us-central1/training/sentiment_training/_model/"
VERSION_NAME="test_v1"
MODEL_NAME="Sentiment"
FRAMEWORK="TensorFlow"

gcloud ai-platform versions create $VERSION_NAME \
  --model $MODEL_NAME \
  --origin $MODEL_DIR \
  --runtime-version=1.15 \
  --framework $FRAMEWORK \
  --python-version=3.7
```

Custom Prediction Routine deployment:

```sh
MODEL_DIR="gs://my-bucket--us-central1/training/sentiment_training/_model/"
VERSION_NAME="test_v1"
MODEL_NAME="Sentiment"
CUSTOM_CODE_PATH="gs://my-bucket--us-central1/packages/custom-op-tf-predictor-0.1.tar.gz"
PREDICTOR_CLASS="predictor.CustomOpTfPredictor"

gcloud beta ai-platform versions create $VERSION_NAME \
  --model $MODEL_NAME \
  --origin $MODEL_DIR \
  --runtime-version=1.15 \
  --python-version=3.7 \
  --package-uris=$CUSTOM_CODE_PATH \
  --prediction-class=$PREDICTOR_CLASS
```

Comment: Can you share how you deploy your model?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I added deployment scripts at the end.

Answer (score 0):

According to Google Support, using an undocumented machine type (`mls1-c4-m4`) as prediction machine solved my problem. I simply added `--machine-type=mls1-c4-m4` at the end of Custom Prediction Routine deployment. This machine has 4gb memory limit but it is still in alpha.

Comment: What is special about this machine type (apart from that it helps you here)?